# Как покрасить сами иконки а не фон иконок?

Tags: html, css

[image: хочу поменять у иконок цвет на салатовый, а в итоге получается что я меняю фон у иконок. как это исправить ?]
хочу поменять у иконок цвет на салатовый, а в итоге получается что я меняю фон у иконок. как это исправить ?
вот код иконок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: предоставьте код иконок для лучшего понимания вопроса

Comment: скинул код иконок

Comment: добавил иконки через fontawesome

Answer (score 2):

я нашёл свою ошибку. надо было указать просто `color`, а я указал `background-color`

Answer (score 1):

попробуй зайти на этот сайт https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

затем напиши код цвета например голубой `#42f5e9`

затем он выдаст фильтр как у меня `filter: invert(99%) sepia(91%) saturate(4443%) hue-rotate(136deg) brightness(103%) contrast(92%);`

дальше просто

```
<img src="example.png alt="example" style="filter invert(99%) sepia(90%) saturate(6656%) hue-rotate(131deg) brightness(96%) contrast(91%);>
```

если что это html код

Comment: <img src="example.png" alt="example" style=" filter invert(99%) sepia(90%) saturate(6656%) hue-rotate(131deg) brightness(96%) contrast(91%); ">